# Iterate through NSManagedObject in order

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have 2 `NSManagedObjects`, table & field and table has a one-to-many relationship with field i.e.

table <------>> field

Up to now I have been able to loop through field like so:

```
for (NSManagedObject *field in [table valueForKey:@"fields"]) {
}
```

however I now need to do this in a specific order using an integer index attribute from the field entity.

I'm new to Core Data so I had assumed that `[table valueForKey:@"fields"]` would return an array of `NSManagedObject`'s but that doesn't seem to be the case.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A to-many relationship is represented as an `NSSet` when using `valueForKey:`.

To turn that into a sorted `NSArray`, you can use the `sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:` method:

```
NSSet *allFields = [table valueForKey:@"fields"];
NSSortDescriptor *indexSortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"index" ascending:YES];
NSArray *sortedFields = [allFields sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[indexSortDescriptor]];
```

Comment: Worked a treat and a lot better than my hack thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`[table valueForKey:@"fields"]` should return `NSOrderSet` not NSArray, so that you can fetch the object using `[orderSet objectAtIndex:index]`.

You must manage the `fields` Relationships in `table` like this below :

[image]

There is a bug when Xcode generate accessors on To-Many-Relationships, check this [Exception thrown in NSOrderedSet generated accessors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7385439/exception-thrown-in-nsorderedset-generated-accessors)

Comment: Just set relationship type to ordered and am now getting the following exception "Cannot create NSSet from object Relationship 'fields' on managed object" Any idea why I might get this?

Comment: @doovers After changing the model, you should regenerate the subclass of NSManagedObject and delete the app on your device or simulator.

Comment: No joy unfortunately but according to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15078679/binding-an-ordered-relationship-with-an-nsarraycontroller#answer-15605624) it seems this won't work or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there are better solutions but this is the best I could come up with!

```
fields = [NSMutableDictionary new];
for (NSManagedObject *fld in [table valueForKey:@"fields"])
{
    [fields setValue:fld forKey:[fld valueForKey:@"index"]];
}

for (int i = 0; i < [fields count]; i++)
{
    field = [fields objectForKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
}
```